# Can .jar get POST params?

Tags: java, post, jar, executable-jar

Can .jar file recieve POST params? I know with command line arguments I can pass data, but as I realise, this data is sent as string:

```
java -jar mylibrary.jar somepostdata
```

I am asking this because I know main class in Java recieves String[] args.. Now, I want to pass POST object, not just plain string. Can it be done?

Comment: Unclear what you want. Usually, `POST` would be a reference to a form post from an HTML web page, which requires an HTTP server. Unless you're referring to something entirely different.

Comment: Yes, I want to recieve HTTP POST request. POST would be sent to that .jar

Comment: Sent by which web server? Or is the code in the jar file implementing it's own web server? A web *page* rendered by a web browser cannot send a POST directly to your jar file. It needs to talk to a web server, e.g. Tomcat, Jetty, ...

Comment: Web page doesen't need to talk to web server Andreas, It can pass POST without interacting with Jetty. That's the all point of HTTP request. I want to process my request (recieve it) by .jar file. I need in that .jar include standalone Jetty.. can I do that? I something like this (no Jetty) enough? http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Comment: Please go and read about POST and about java jars

Comment: ACV, ok. Where can I read about it?

Comment: @DarioBB A [Web Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) "is an information technology that processes requests via HTTP". It's in the definition of the term "Web Server", so yeah, you'll need a Web Server. --- Also, you don't send information to the Jar. The command-line you've shown will pass arguments to the `main()` method of your main class. When running a Web Server, it will listen to requests from the Web Browser, and will call your code (not the `main()` method, but some other method) with the values posted by the web page.

Comment: Andreas, .jar file can have main method. So why you say "you don't send information to the jar", if jar can have main method and inside can be defined running web server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment below you would require a Jetty Web Server. A Jetty Web Server is a JAR file. So basically you would expose an endpoint. Your application jQuery or whatever you decide to do will send to this JAR at the endpoint and port number.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can I send from AngularJS or JQuery string directly to .jar file (I would like not to use servlets or similar stuff)? I did not realise do I need to include in that .jar or you ment something else?

p.s. "Send a String array to the command line and your Java application sends out HTTP POST requests." - How you ment to do this.. I wanted that my .jar recieves HTTP request? 
Is this enough without Jetty to use in my .jar? 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Comment: Basically you accept the String array in your Java main method. As part of your Java application you have code that will make HTTP requests. You could even have a Jetty Web Server which is typically a JAR file, not WAR. That way you can send HTTP requests.

Comment: Rajjiv Jain, you sad it will make HTTP request. I don't want in my .jar to make HTTP requests. I want to make HTTP POST request for example, from Jquery, and pass it to .jar. Can .jar accept that and process that POST request?

Comment: Thanks Rajiv Jain. So I must just include in my .jar file Jetty .jars to be able to handle POST request and that's it? P.S. why Jetty, why not Tomcat for example?

Comment: You could use Tomcat but Tomcat accepts a WAR file. Your question was asking about a JAR file and Jetty is a standalone application. Therefore a JAR file. That's right, you include the jetty dependencies. Does that make sense? Does my answer make sense? If yes please accept my answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks man, that makes sense very much. I can with Jetty do what I need later. So If I am right, I send the string from JQuery to my .jar, and then in my .jar I use native Jetty methods to deal with my string from which I can form a POST request and process it?

Comment: You can send your String to the jar through a endpoint such as http://example.com:8080/acceptString. There will be a HTTP POST. Then you could use Jetty methods to deal with your String. Such as translating your String to a Java POJO. Does that make sense?

Comment: Rajiv Jain, one more question. I've tried to implement Jetty and since that was not been easy for me, I wonder can it be done without Jetty? Do I even need Jetty? Can my .jar use some native Java stuff to deal with POST and GET request, but at same time, that everything it remains in .jar file instead of .war file we disscussed? Basically, I would like accept in my .jar any POST or GET data and then process it